# Implement a loop that keeps the user entering the input until the condition is not met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

Hey guys I hope you're doing well.

The problem I have is that my loop is not well defined, therefore the condition that I give it is not met. The print of the DataFrame that I implemented inside the while loop is not performed when the condition is not met.

This is the code I have so far. By implementing the while loop it stopped returning me the modified dataframe. As I said before, the loop is poorly constructed.

Dataframe content:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
A  5  3  X  X  7  X  X  X  X
B  6  X  X  1  9  5  X  X  X
C  X  9  8  X  X  X  X  6  X
D  8  X  X  X  6  X  X  X  3
E  4  X  X  8  X  3  X  X  1
F  7  X  X  X  2  X  X  X  6
G  X  6  X  X  X  X  2  8  X
H  X  X  X  4  1  9  X  X  5
I  X  X  X  X  8  X  X  7  9
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

def modifyDF():

    T = pd.read_fwf('file', header= None, names=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'])
    T = T.rename(index={0:'A',1:'B',2:'C',3:'D',4:'E',5:'F',6:'G',7:'H',8:'I'})
    df = pd.DataFrame(T)
    print(T,'\n')
    
    x= input('row: ')
    y= input('column: ')
    v= input('value: ')
    
    while 'X' in df:
        f = df.loc[x,y]= v
        print(f)
    
    while 'X' not in df:
        break

modifyDF()
```

Expected OUTPUT:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
A  5  3  X  X  7  X  X  X  X
B  6  X  X  1  9  5  X  X  X
C  X  9  8  X  X  X  X  6  X
D  8  X  X  X  6  X  X  X  3
E  4  X  X  8  X  3  X  X  1
F  7  X  X  X  2  X  X  X  6
G  X  6  X  X  X  X  2  8  X
H  X  X  X  4  1  9  X  X  5
I  X  X  X  X  8  X  X  7  9

row: D      #For example
column: 2   #For example
value: 1    #For example

#The modified dataframe:

   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
A  5  3  X  X  7  X  X  X  X
B  6  X  X  1  9  5  X  X  X
C  X  9  8  X  X  X  X  6  X
D  8  1  X  X  6  X  X  X  3
E  4  X  X  8  X  3  X  X  1
F  7  X  X  X  2  X  X  X  6
G  X  6  X  X  X  X  2  8  X
H  X  X  X  4  1  9  X  X  5
I  X  X  X  X  8  X  X  7  9

#The goal would be for this to run like a loop until there are no 'X' left in the dataframe.
```

I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: What is `while 'X' in df` meant to do? If it should check if there is any "X" in the df, it would loop forever because the code in the loop would at most overwrite one "X" in first iteration and no more in further iterations.

Comment: I believe all you need is `df.loc[x, y] = v` and then return. No while loops. Just `print(df)` after calling `modifyDF()`. For *#The goal would be for this to run like a loop until there are no 'X' left in the dataframe.*, you could use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) : `df.replace('X', v)`

Comment: Thank's for your response @SomeDude. To `return`  the function `df.loc[x, y] = v` what should I do? Because if I `return` , `df.replace('X', v)` won't work right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you'd better not loop through a pandas DataFrame, but use more pythonic methods. In this case, you need to move your while loop a bit higher in your code, before the input statements, so your function would become:

```
def modifyDF():

    T = pd.read_fwf('file', header=None, names=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'])
    T = T.rename(index={0:'A',1:'B',2:'C',3:'D',4:'E',5:'F',6:'G',7:'H',8:'I'})
    df = pd.DataFrame(T)
    print(T,'\n')

    while df.isin(['X']).any().any():
        x = input('row: ')
        y = input('column: ')
        v = input('value: ')
        
        df.loc[x,y] = v
        f = v
        print(f)
```

Also remember that `f = df.loc[x,y]= v` is wrong in Python.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ali. I've implemented the code improvements but it doesn't show me the inputs. Is it because they are inserted in the while loop?

Comment: It worked perfectly. I have changed something so that it is to my liking in terms of aesthetics. I need to learn more about how to implement and use the `.isin` and `any()`. Thank you Ali. The answer is very clear!

Comment: Glad it helped. You can check out https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html to learn more. You can also accept and upvote the answer. I upvoted your question, so now you have enough reputation to upvote. Good luck!

Comment: Done! Good luck too mate :)